# Django allauth: Visit login page but already logged in

Tags: django, django-allauth

Can you set django-allauth to have a redirect link if you visit the login page and you're already logged in?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, do you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this recently. You can add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'some redirect url'` to your **settings.py** file. All-auth will use this as the redirect URL for when you log in, and if you visit the login page after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I found that along with @zubhav's suggestion, adding  ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS=False in your project's settings.py file will make sure you see the login page